# Position Div inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that blurs an image and a text box:

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 30px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;

}

.background-image {
    padding: 30px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-image: url(http://localhost:2359/images/6H.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    height: 800px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class=" hero-spacer">
    <div class="background-image"></div>
        <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>TEXT</p>   
        </header>
    </div>
```

This is the result that I get:

[image]

My question is how can I put the text under the image, on it, and not under it?
I don't know what need to be done.

Comment: Use `position` and `z-index` CSS rules

Answer (score 2):

Try to use absolute position in CSS for inner contaners:

```
.jumbotron, .background-image {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And relative position for outer container:

```
.hero-spacer {
    position: relative;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3a1w273/1/

Answer (score 0):

make both

```
position: relative;
```

and adjust jumbotron with something like

```
top: -100px;
```

and

```
left: 100px;
```

attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4dpzf8v/2/

Comment: well it does work in my jsfiddle, as you can see. so you might have done the mentioned corrections wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The below should sort you out.

---

```css
.hero-spacer {
  position: relative;
}
.jumbotron {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  color: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.background-image {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://localhost:2359/images/6H.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=" hero-spacer">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </header>
</div>
```